# word_delimiter with split_on_numerics removes all tokens

Tags: elasticsearch, tokenize

When analyzing `alpha 1a beta`, I want the outcome of tokens to be `[alpha 1 a beta]`. Why does `myAnalyzer` not do the trick?

```
POST myindex
{
  "settings" : {
    "analysis" : {
      "analyzer" : {
        "myAnalyzer" : {
          "type" : "custom",
          "tokenizer" : "standard",
          "filter" : [ "split_on_numerics" ]
        }
      },
      "filter" : {
        "split_on_numerics" : {
          "type" : "word_delimiter",
          "split_on_numerics" : true,
          "split_on_case_change" : false,
          "generate_word_parts" : false,
          "generate_number_parts" : false,
          "catenate_all" : false
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Now when I run

```
GET /myindex/_analyze?analyzer=myAnalyzer&text=alpha 1a beta
```

no tokens are returned. Again, why?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To achieve this in the custom [word-delimiter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-word-delimiter-tokenfilter.html) filter one needs to set `"generate_word_parts" : true`  and `"generate_number_parts" : true`.

This essentially ensures that an "alphanumeric token" when split should generate its numeric and word parts.

Example filter would be as follows :

```
{
  "settings" : {
    "analysis" : {
      "analyzer" : {
        "myAnalyzer" : {
          "type" : "custom",
          "tokenizer" : "standard",
          "filter" : [ "split_on_numerics" ]
        }
      },
      "filter" : {
        "split_on_numerics" : {
          "type" : "word_delimiter",
          "split_on_numerics" : true,
          "split_on_case_change" : false,
          "generate_word_parts" : true,
          "generate_number_parts" : true,
          "catenate_all" : false
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

In case you want the original term  `"1a"` to be indexed to you need to set

```
preserve_original : true
```

to be indexed one

Comment: Worked like charm..Thanks